# Adding Libraries back into Windows 7 after removing them

Tags: windows-7, restore, libraries

I downloaded your .reg file to remove libraries from Windows 7 permanently.  However, since then I found better ways of working around this.  I tried modifying the downloaded file to reverse the procedure but this didn't work.  How can I get libraries back after removing them?  I don't want to do a full system restore as I would lose other things I would like to keep.

Here is the title of the original solution I tried:
How To Disable and Remove Libraries from Windows 7

Comment: could you please provide some links?

Comment: "Whose" .reg file?

Answer (score 1):

Try `Restore Default Settings.reg` from the archive provided here http://www.askvg.com/how-to-disable-libraries-feature-in-windows-7/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I downloaded your .zip file and ran the Restore Default Settings.reg file but this only gave me a Libraries (32 Bit) directory that can't be opened in my Desktop folder.  When I ran the file it seemed to indicate that everything was being added correctly.  I have a 64bit OS.  Could that be the hangup?